# Mostrar archivo PDF sin tener que descargarlo

Tags: html, pdf

La página es muy simple: fondo negro con el logo de un bar centrado y un menú desplegable para ver los datos de contacto y la carta del lugar; cada opción me lleva a otro html. El problema que tengo es que el archivo PDF se visualiza perfectamente en los navegadores de mi computadora (safari y chrome), pero en el navegador del celular (también chrome) sólo me aparece la posibilidad de descargarlo. El código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Carta</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="style2.css" media='all' />  
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="./CARTA.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

¿Cómo hacer que sólo se visualice independientemente de que pueda o no descargarse?

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esta librería  https://viewerjs.org/instructions/ , permite visualizar pdf, la he probado en móvil con emulador `Android` en entorno local con `php` y para mi funciona.

[image: Visualizar pdf en android con viewerjs]

Ahora bien use el siguiente código, después de `ViewerJs/#` escribes la ruta donde se encuentra el pdf, para mi caso esta en la misma raíz de `index` así que voy un directorio hacia atrás `../` y el nombre del archivo, también permite `http://` pero debe tener en cuenta políticas `cross-origin`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container">
    <iframe style="float:right;" src = "/ViewerJS/#../todo.pdf" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```